# How to find all links / pages on a website

Tags: directory, web-crawler

Is it possible to find all the pages and links on ANY given website? I'd like to enter a URL and produce a directory tree of all links from that site?

I've looked at HTTrack but that downloads the whole site and I simply need the directory tree.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Check out [linkchecker](https://linkchecker.github.io/linkchecker/man/linkchecker.html)—it will crawl the site (while obeying `robots.txt`) and generate a report. From there, you can script up a solution for creating the directory tree.

Comment: thank you so much Hank! Perfect - exactly what I needed. Very much appreciated.

Comment: A nice tool. I was using "XENU link sleuth before". Linkchecker is far more verbose.

Comment: how do I do that myself? and what if there is no robots.txt in a web site?

Comment: @MariusKavansky How do you manually crawl a website? Or how do you build a crawler? I'm not sure I understand your question. If there is no `robots.txt` file, that just means you can crawl to your heart's content.

Comment: And this is available in Ubuntu's repository (actually it works with Windows/Mac/Linux)

Comment: Such a great little program!

Comment: hi guys, linkchecker has not worked for me when I scan the site it only returns a report of broken links. Very small report. while it does they it checked thousands of links but I can't see where those are reported. Using version 9.3 can you please help?

Comment: how to send output to file with `--out` or `-o`?

Comment: Usual command to write to file is `linkchecker https://example.com --file-output=csv --verbose` . Different formats can be chosen too.

Comment: It did not work. It reported an SSL handshake problem and the execution was terminated.

Answer (score 65):

If you have the developer console (JavaScript) in your browser, you can type this code in:

```
urls = document.querySelectorAll('a'); for (url in urls) console.log(urls[url].href);
```

Shortened:

```
n=$$('a');for(u in n)console.log(n[u].href)
```

Comment: What about "Javascript-ed" urls?

Comment: Like what? What do you mean?

Comment: I mean a link done using Javascript. Your solution wouldn't show it.

Comment: @ElectroBit I really like it, but I'm not sure what I'm looking at?  What is the `$$` operator?  Or is that just [an arbitrary function name,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463867/javascript-double-dollar-sign) same as `n=ABC(''a');`  I'm not understanding how `urls` gets all the 'a' tagged elements.  Can you explain?  I'm assuming its not jQuery.  What prototype library function are we talking?

Comment: @zipzit In a handful of browsers, `$$()` is basically shorthand for `document.querySelectorAll()`. More info at this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: There is no complete computable solution to traversing javascripted urls beyond some very rudimentary attempts. At least this tip is working with the DOM and not the HTML source.

Comment: Sadly, in 2023, this little snippet isn't working for me from Chrome's console.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative might be

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a")).map(x => x.href)
```

With your `$$(` its even shorter

```js
Array.from($$("a")).map(x => x.href)
```

Or even more shorter

Array.from doesn't need map

```js
Array.from($$("a"), (x) => x.href)
```

or

```js
[...$$("a")].map((x) => x.href)
```

or

```js
$x('//a[@href!="#"]').map(({ href }) => href)
```

Comment: plus 1 - like that you are using modern JS.  I ran this program, and while it returned a few links, it didn't return all of the .html pages that are on the top level.  Is there a reason why all the pages don't return in the array list?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If this is a programming question, then I would suggest you write your own regular expression to parse all the retrieved contents. Target tags are IMG and A for standard HTML. For JAVA,

```
final String openingTags = "(<a [^>]*href=['\"]?|<img[^> ]* src=['\"]?)";
```

this along with Pattern and Matcher classes should detect the beginning of the tags. Add LINK tag if you also want CSS.

However, it is not as easy as you may have intially thought. Many web pages are not well-formed. Extracting all the links programmatically that human being can "recognize" is really difficult if you need to take into account all the irregular expressions.

Good luck!

Comment: No no no no, [don't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/113632), it makes Baby Jesus cry!

Answer (score -1):

```
function getalllinks($url) {
    $links = array();
    if ($fp = fopen($url, 'r')) {
        $content = '';
        while ($line = fread($fp, 1024)) {
            $content. = $line;
        }
    }
    $textLen = strlen($content);
    if ($textLen > 10) {
        $startPos = 0;
        $valid = true;
        while ($valid) {
            $spos = strpos($content, '<a ', $startPos);
            if ($spos < $startPos) $valid = false;
            $spos = strpos($content, 'href', $spos);
            $spos = strpos($content, '"', $spos) + 1;
            $epos = strpos($content, '"', $spos);
            $startPos = $epos;
            $link = substr($content, $spos, $epos - $spos);
            if (strpos($link, 'http://') !== false) $links[] = $link;
        }
    }
    return $links;
}
```

try this code....

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: Eh, it's a little **long.**

Comment: Completely unnecessary to parse the html in this manner in php. http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php PHP does have the ability to understand the DOM!