# Uncaught ReferenceError: $$ is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I'm trying to programmatically create a **pie chart** in hopes of turning it into a React Component to reuse. Basically I need a pie chart that is clickable and each slice expands into a whole pie when clicked. I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/07/designing-simple-pie-charts-with-css/) to making **pie charts** and at the bottom, I have a piece of **JS** that I tried to test out. I ended up getting `Uncaught Reference Error: $$ is not defined.` Here's a screenshot of error message.

[image]

My understanding is that this is not **jQuery** and is simply Vanilla JS. I'm not sure if this is true. I imported **jQuery** via a **CDN** and still got the same error. I read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463867/javascript-double-dollar-sign) and I'm thinking `$$` is simply a kind of variable name notation.

This is the code I have in `index.html`, nothing groundbreaking.

```
<body>
  <div class="pie">20%</div>
  <div class="pie">60%</div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $$('.pie').forEach(function(pie) {
      var p = parseFloat(pie.textContent);
      var NS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
      var svg = document.createElementNS(NS, "svg");
      var circle = document.createElementNS(NS, "circle");
      var title = document.createElementNS(NS, "title");
      circle.setAttribute("r", 16);
      circle.setAttribute("cx", 16);
      circle.setAttribute("cy", 16);
      circle.setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", p + " 100");
      svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 32 32");
      title.textContent = pie.textContent;
      pie.textContent = '';
      svg.appendChild(title);
      svg.appendChild(circle);
      pie.appendChild(svg);
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

What's causing the error? Am I misunderstanding? Is the tutorial I'm following outdated/wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Where is `$$` defined ?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide your code als text - not als an image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Include the following:

```
function $$(selector, context) {
  context = context || document;
  var elements = context.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(elements);
}
```

According to the author, Lea Verou, she mentions:

> in the book the definition of $$() is given in the introduction, but since this is an excerpt, it doesn’t include that.

Comment: Oh thank you!! This is super helpful and fixed it. My hunches were right :D Anyways, I'll accept as answer once SO allows it :)

Answer (score 2):

From **[tutorial](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/07/designing-simple-pie-charts-with-css/)** you mention in your question i got something that will **help** you.

[image]

**Also**, you need to **wrap** your `code` in,

```
$(function(){....});
```

As you mention jquery in your tags.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use single $ instead double $$ on `$$('.pie')` so your code like `$('.pie')` ?

And check if you already to include jQuery

Here is helpful link

> http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp
>
> https://api.jquery.com/