# What does it mean $ and $$ in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Please explain the meaning of the $ and $$

This is sample code use $ and $$:
https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip/blob/master/cytoscape-qtip.js

what mean this code use $:

```
var $qtipContainer = $('<div></div>');
```

Comment: I don't think there is any meaning

Comment: Both `$` and `$$` are valid names for variables, they have no special meaning.

Comment: Just aliases to the 2 global variables you can see passed at the end of the file (jQuery and cytoscape)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The whole code is just a function call with two arguments:

```
;(function( $, $$ ){ 'use strict';
  // skipped
})(
  typeof jQuery !== 'undefined' ? jQuery : null,
  typeof cytoscape !== 'undefined' ? cytoscape : null
);
```

The first argument is `jQuery` global variable (or `null`, if `jQuery` is undefined), and the second is `cytoscape` global variable (or `null`, if is undefined).

Answer (score 6):

In the browser developer tools console - at least in Firefox, IE11, (can't test lesser IE's), Edge and Chrome - `$` and `$$` do have particular functions (if the page hasn't defined those vars) - see MDN Documentation for helper commands in the [Web Console Helpers](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/web_console/helpers/index.html).

Comment: Depends which browser you use (that's Firefox documentation, not something standard), and really that's just another example of defining some functions and naming them $ and $$.

Comment: yes, it's firefox documentation, but I actually tried in IE11, Edge and Chrum, and all behave identically to Firefox - I chose to post Firefox documentation because I find Mozilla documentation easy to understand and they often document even features not supported in Mozilla - I wouldn't say it works in those browsers if I didn't know it works in those browsers :p

Answer (score 3):

`$` and `$$` are valid variable names in JavaScript, they have no special meaning.

Usually they set their value to library instances, in your example if you check the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) call, at the end of the file you'll see that `$` is [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) in this case if it is defined and `$$` is [cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/).

See the corresponding code part:

```
;(function( $, $$ ){ 'use strict';
  // ...
})(
  typeof jQuery !== 'undefined' ? jQuery : null,
  typeof cytoscape !== 'undefined' ? cytoscape : null
);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a naming convention in JavaScript for variables that store JavaScript objects. Their name should start with `$`. Exactly like in your example:

```
var $qtipContainer = $('<div></div>');
```

Because JavaScript is untyped language, this is useful way for programmers to distinguish whether variable stores jQuery object or for example DOM object.

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the [source code](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip/blob/master/cytoscape-qtip.js#L395-L398), `$` is jQuery, and `$$` is cytoscape.

Besides, the `$` symbol is perfectly valid variable name.

Answer (score 0):

It's [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), a JS framework for DOM-manipulation and all sorts of other fun stuff.

Answer (score 0):

$ sign is a valid identifier in JavaScript. $$ was a notation that used back when packer was popular but no significance now.

[Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463867/javascript-double-dollar-sign)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using prototype javascript then $$() & $()  are selectors.
For more information visit https://www.tutorialspoint.com/prototype/prototype_utility_methods.htm