# How to locate where a function was defined with dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-inspector

I have a big website and I'm trying to figure out if/why jquery(or something using those functions) is present on it (or at least something using the same function)

When I type $ and $$ into the console it shows they are functions, but i can't figure out where they have been defined.

In chrome they just say [native code], and when I right click and click "show function definition" nothing happens.

What else can I do?

Edit: Both of these functions actually still show up on an empty page in both firefox and chrome... is it a built in function? I can't find any evidence of this by searching on google.

They seem to function like querySelector and querySelectorAll.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to some belief, these are actually not jQuery in the page. In chrome these are defined in dev tools for convenience and are just aliases for `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll`

More info:

- [$ Variable (Dollar Sign) in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778477/variable-dollar-sign-in-chrome)
- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/utilities/

Answer (score 0):

add debugger to those lines where those functions are used, then use `step` debug to pause on each line, it should lead you to the function definition

If that function is not used, in Firefox typing the function name gives a button(right arrow) to jump to definition

[image]

Comment: they're not used anywhere that i know, I'm just in the console

Comment: firefox does not give that button for $ and $$

Comment: well, it does on this site, this site must have jquery. it looks different if you do it in a new tab.

Comment: I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39891230/5798816
Thanks for the question, got to know an interesting thing today :)

Comment: that just seems to say its probably a library, but doesn't explain why they're there by default

Comment: that answer having a link to this documentation where it explains meaning of $ and $$
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers

Comment: oh so it only works in the console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242861/discussion-between-harsh-rohila-and-stackers).