# What's the meaning of "$$("a")" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the meaning of `$$("a")` in JavaScript?, Is that something relevant to jQuery?

Typed it into browser's console, it works.

Comment: @LucaKiebel Yeah, thanks.

Comment: That's Google's [Command Line API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference). `$` is `document.querySelector`, `$$` is `document.querySelectorAll`, though relying on that behavior for `$` is a bad idea because on many sites it will be replaced by jQuery.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463867/javascript-double-dollar-sign

Comment: All the linked dup questions are discussing specific libraries that have functions w/ `$$`.  Was OP referring to those libs or to the "build-in" expression in Chrome?  (Or another popular browser)?

Comment: The second link answers OP's question.

Comment: @riv The second link is a different question that happens to also have an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome `$$` is an alias for `document.querySelectorAll`.  Learn more on the [expressions page](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/expressions).