# what is $$ before varible in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Hi I am newbie in typesript and while I reading redux source code pieces I found the issue and search a lot of stuff and can not track its tail.

```
declare global {
  interface SymbolConstructor {
    readonly observable: symbol
  }
}

const $$observable = /* #__PURE__ */ (() =>
  (typeof Symbol === 'function' && Symbol.observable) || '@@observable')()

export default $$observable
```

To clarify its complexity this is the link of code:https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/utils/symbol-observable.ts

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463867/javascript-double-dollar-sign, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19338493/what-is-the-double-dollar-sign-used-for-in-angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ and also $$ are valid variable names in javascript with no special meaning whatsoever and thus also have no special meaning in typescript.