# Downloading all Urls accessible under a given domain with wget without saving the actual pages?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

Trying to determine all the valid urls under a given domain without having the mirror the site locally.

People generally want to download all the pages but I just want to get a list of the direct urls under a given domain (e.g. `www.example.com`), which would be something like

- `www.example.com/page1`
- `www.example.com/page2`
- etc.

Is there a way to use `wget` to do this? or is there a better approach for this?

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439326/how-to-find-all-links-pages-on-a-website

Comment: Do you have any example of your output, and what you want to display?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I had to find my own answer:

the tool I use was **httrack**.

```
httrack -p0 -r2 -d www.example.com
```

- the *-p0* option tells it to just scan (not save pages);
- the *-rx* option tells it the depth of the search
- the *-d* options tells it to stay on the same principal domain

there is even a -%L  to add the scanned URL to the specified file but it doesn't seem to work. But that's not a problem, because under the hts-cache directory you can find a **TSV** file named *new.txt* containing all the urls visited  and some additional information about it. I could extract the URLs from it with the following python code:

```
with open("hts-cache/new.txt") as f:
    t = csv.DictReader(f,delimiter='\t')
    for l in t:
        print l['URL']
```

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear if you want to use wget to determine these URLs, but to answer your question regarding not saving the site you could use "--output-document=file" or simply "-O file".

```
wget -O /dev/null <your-site>
```

If you have a list of URLs, and want to check if they work you can check for an exit code greater than 0. I.e.

```
while read URL
do
  wget -O /dev/null $URL >/dev/null 2>&1
  [ $? -gt 0 ] && echo "ERROR retrieving $URL"
done < your-URL-list.txt
```

Comment: No, If I wanted only to check if the pages where there, I could use wget --spider, but I want it to find all of the urls and list them on stdout or in a file.