# Link checker within R

Tags: r, web-scraping

Is there a way within R to list (find) all links for a given webpage?
I'd like to enter a URL and produce a directory tree of all links from that site. The purpose is to find the relevant sub-page to scrape.

Here is link to similar question on SO but without R solution. Thanks.

[Link here to similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439326/how-to-find-all-links-pages-on-a-website)

There is a suggested solution with [Linkchecker](http://wummel.github.io/linkchecker/) but that runs under Python, is there something within R?

Comment: This isn't a good question for SO since it's not about programming. But you should check the web task view: http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/WebTechnologies.html - there should be all you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `rvest` can do what you are looking for...

```
library("rvest")
# some url with a bunch of links...
url <- "http://www.drudgereport.com"
url %>% html %>% html_nodes("a") %>% xml_attr("href")
```