# How would I find all the sub domains of this page

Tags: dns, subdomain

So I've tried many ways of looking up subdomains of this domain. I get nothing. I know it has sub domains because I have the Info for one. The website is a godaddy website. It's kitnkai.com the sun domain I have is kitnkai.com/qr.html I know it has a bunch of subdomains but I can't find a list of anymore. Help?!?

Comment: That's not a subdomain, that's a web page.  A subdomain would be mysubdomain.kitnkai.com.

Comment: So then what would a /example.html be called?

Comment: @Mikejones123 — A path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all links / pages on a website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439326/how-to-find-all-links-pages-on-a-website)

Comment: @quentin is there a way to look up all paths associated with a domain. I've tried a couple of the links in that thread you posted but nothing has popped up. Is it possibly the creator blocked it?